# What is the Strength of a Landing Bay?

Tags: rogue-trader

In Rogue Trader's *Battlefield Koronus* book, page 36, it indicates that "a Landing Bay comes equipped with one squadron per point of strength". While it indicates clearly what a squadron can entail, it is unclear on what a landing bay's strength is. The chart on page 41 only indicates **Power**, **Space** and **SP** (which is Ship Points, yes?). How do you determine the **Strength** of a landing bay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Page 35 of the Battlefleet Koronus book has your answer.**

Table 1-9: starship weapons on page 35 is a table of different starship weapons, including landing bays. It includes the strength value of every weapon, as well as other relevant stats.

Specifically for landing bays, all landing bays have a strength of 2, except for the Jovian-pattern Escort Bay that has a strength of 1.

The table on page 41 also includes the landing bays, but has less information than table 1-9.